# Reset TextBox Undo/Redo

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox

My program displays a window with a textbox. My code populates the textbox before the dialog is displayed.

I want undo and redo to work normally; *however* my code's initial population of the textbox should not be an undoable action.

Once the textbox has been populated, how can I clear the Undo/Redo actions?

*Unfortunately, I'm very frustrated learning WPF right now and am amazed at the things it either cannot do or can only do by jumping through hoops. So I'm not very optimistic about this simple request but just thought I'd ask.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do:

```
textbox1.Text = "Starting text.";
textbox1.IsUndoEnabled = false;
textbox1.IsUndoEnabled = true;
```

Comment: Did you try this? It didn't seem to work for me. (I was still able to _undo_ the starting text.)

Comment: Works for me, pressing CTRL+Z doesn't clear the box, how are you doing an 'undo'?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It does work. I had a mix up in the order my code was running.